# Downloaded and imported Json Are Gone when i close my app and reopen it

Tags: android

When i Download The Json file From The Server And once I Close my App and Reopen it again All the  Servers  that Are Downloaded and Imported Are gone..

The Question Is..

How To Keep  the Json Files Downloaded and Imported When I Close My App...

**my code:**

```
//GET INPUT FROM STREAM
InputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String line;
StringBuffer jsonData=new StringBuffer();
```

Answer (score 1):

After you download them you should save all the data into a `SharedPreferences`, so when you app opens again it will pull the data from there

To implement manage of `SharedPreferences` do this

To set the values just do this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("myData", jsonData);
 editor.apply();
```

To retrieve this data do this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String data = prefs.getString("myData","");
```

Call the data from the shared preferences when your app restarts, so you will be downloading the data -> storing it into `sharedpreferences` -> call again the data from `sharedpreferences` when app is reopened

For more info you should read the official SharedPrefs doc here : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

hope it helps !

Happy coding !

Comment: Ohh Thanks I hope It Works Btw last Question What Activity i should put That Code ?? In The MainActivity.java ??

Comment: Hi, you should use this code at the activity you download the json, there you will use the first part to save the json after downloading it, and then you can use the retrieve method in any activity you want